# Creating graph for pgRouting with PostGIS?

Tags: pgrouting

Let the line A (0.98,0.562,3.27536,5.9723) and line B (3.33221,5.899287,10.7656,9.653627). Does pgrouting take a point near (3.27536,5.9723) or (3.33221,5.899287) as a node? Really theses two points are just one, they have only a little error range.

Answer (score 1):

When you build your graph

[Creating graph for pgrouting](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/src/topology/doc/pgr_createTopology.html)

you need to specify a snapping range. This way the point that are really close will snapped into the same node..

```
 SELECT assign_vertex_id(table_name, snapping_range, geometry_column_name, edge_id_column_name);
```

example

```
SELECT assign_vertex_id('ways', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid');
```

Comment: That link is gone... Now, the link is http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/forum/pgrouting.postlbs.org/wiki/pgRoutingDocs/preparation/topology.html